# how to set the image dynamically in react native for Image component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building an app which contains a menu to set the theme color and the images inside. There is a video inside the app which has colors, so when you select a theme in the modal, the video should change to a different color video. So, I am trying to fetch the async variable of the theme and load the right video source based on that and the selected color from the theme. How can I achieve this to be more specific how can i change the "source" of the video dynamically ? i tried the uri but it did not work, it prevents error but it did not display anything

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image, Modal, Platform } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { RadioButton } from 'react-native-paper';
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Video, ResizeMode } from 'expo-av';

export default function StopwatchScreen() {
    const [menuVisible, setMenuVisible] = useState(false);

    const videoArrows = useRef(null);

    const [themeColor, setThemeColor] = useState('');

    let getArrowVideoPath;


    const setThemeFunction = (color) => {
        if(color === "blue") {
            getArrowVideoPath = require('../assets/images/blue_arrows.png');
        } else if(color === "red"){
            getArrowVideoPath = require('../assets/images/red_arrows.png');
        }
    }

    const handleLapButtonPress = useCallback(() => {
        console.log("lap clicked");
    }, [isRunning, time]);

    const handleStartButtonPress = () => {
        console.log("clicked 2");
    };

    const toggleMenu = () => {
        setMenuVisible(!menuVisible);
    }

    const retrieveTheme = async () => {
        try {
            const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('theme');

            if (jsonValue !== null) {
                const parsedValue = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
                setThemeColor(parsedValue);
                console.log("parsedValue: ", parsedValue);
            } else {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify('blue'));
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // error reading value
            console.log('error: ', e);
        }
    };

    const saveTheme = async (value) => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(value));
        setThemeColor(value);
        setThemeFunction(themeColor);
        console.log('saved');
        console.log('saved theme: ', themeColor);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveTheme();
        setThemeFunction(themeColor);
    }, []);
    

    return (
        
        <View style={[styles.container, Platform.OS === 'android' && styles.androidPadding]}>
        
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={[styles.title, styles.textFont]}>Futuristic Stopwatch</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleMenu}>
                    <Image source={require('../assets/images/three_dots.png')} style={styles.dotsIcon} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <Modal
                transparent={true}
                animationType="slide"
                visible={menuVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => setMenuVisible(false)}
            >
                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.modalContent}>
                        <Ionicons name="close-circle" size={32} color="#11167F" onPress={() => setMenuVisible(false)} style={styles.closeButton} />
                        <View style={styles.sectionTitle}>
                            <Text style={[styles.sectionTitleText, styles.textFont]}>Theme</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.radioBox}>
                            <View style={styles.radioOptions}>
                                <RadioButton
                                    value="blue"
                                    status={ themeColor === 'blue' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked' }
                                    onPress={() => saveTheme('blue')}
                                    color="blue"
                                />
                                 <Text style={[styles.textFont]}>Blue</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.radioOptions}>
                                <RadioButton
                                    value="red"
                                    status={ themeColor === 'red' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked' }
                                    onPress={() => saveTheme('red')}
                                    color="#DE382A"
                                />
                                <Text style={[styles.textFont]}>Red</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>

            <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                <View style={styles.rowArrow}>
                    <Video
                        ref={videoArrows}
                        style={{width: '100%'}}
                        source={getArrowVideoPath}
                        useNativeControls={false}
                        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
                        onError={(error) => console.error("Video playback error:", error)}
                        isLooping={true}
                        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => {
                            if (!status.isPlaying) {
                                // Handle playback stopped or ended
                                //console.log("status: ", status);
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.controls}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleStartButtonPress} style={[styles.controlButtonBorder, { backgroundColor: isRunning ? "#340e0d" : "#0a2a12" }]}>
                        <View style={styles.controlButton}>
                            <Text style={{ color: isRunning ? "#ea4c49" : "#37d05c" }}>{isRunning ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLapButtonPress} style={[styles.controlButtonBorder, { backgroundColor: isRunning ? "#333333" : "#1c1c1e" }]}>
                        <View style={styles.controlButton}>
                            <Text style={{ color: isRunning ? "#fff" : "#9d9ca2" }}>{isRunning ? 'Lap' : 'Reset'}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );

    
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      padding: 0,
    },
    androidPadding: {
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 25 : 0,
    },
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom: 0,
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#0a1055',
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        //fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
    },
    dotsIcon: {
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
    modalContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    },
    textFont: {
        fontFamily: 'Orbitron Black',
    },
    modalContent: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        padding: 20,
        borderRadius: 10,
        elevation: 5,
    },
    closeButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
    },
    sectionTitle: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    sectionTitleText: {
        fontFamily: 'Orbitron Black',
    },
    radioBox: {
        marginTop: 20,
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        width: 300,
    },
    radioOptions: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom: 10,
    },

    contentContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#0E1B84',
    },
    rowArrow: {
        flex: 0.1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginBottom: 0,
    },
    rowHud: {
        flex: 0.5,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginBottom: 0
    },
    timerOverlay: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '50%', // Adjust as needed
        left: '50%', // Adjust as needed
        transform: [{ translateX: -90 }, { translateY: -30 }],
        fontSize: 50,
        color: 'white',
    },
    hoursTimerOverlay: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '35%', // Adjust as needed
        left: '50%', // Adjust as needed
        transform: [{ translateX: -30 }, { translateY: -30 }],
        fontSize: 35,
        color: 'white',
    },
    centisecondsTimerOverlay: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '71%', // Adjust as needed
        left: '50%', // Adjust as needed
        transform: [{ translateX: -15 }, { translateY: -30 }],
        fontSize: 35,
        color: 'white',
    },
    controls: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingRight: 20,
    },
    controlButtonBorder: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        borderRadius: 70,
    },
    controlButton: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        width: 65,
        height: 65,
        borderRadius: 65,
        borderColor: "#000",
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it this way, maybe it helps someone looking for this answer

```
    const [getArrowVideoPath, setArrowVideoPath] = useState(require('../assets/videos/blue_arrows.mp4'));

const setThemeFunction = (color) => {
        if(color === "blue") {
            setArrowVideoPath(require('../assets/videos/blue_arrows.mp4'));
            getHudVideoPath = require('../assets/images/blue_hud.png');
            getCirclesImagePath = require('../assets/images/blue_circles.png');
        } else if(color === "red"){
            setArrowVideoPath(require('../assets/videos/red_arrows.mp4'));
            getHudVideoPath = require('../assets/images/red_hud.png');
            getCirclesImagePath = require('../assets/images/red_circles.png');
        }
    }

                    <View style={styles.radioBox}>
                            <View style={styles.radioOptions}>
                                <RadioButton
                                    value="blue"
                                    status={ themeColor === 'blue' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked' }
                                    onPress={() => {saveTheme('blue');setArrowVideoPath(require('../assets/videos/blue_arrows.mp4'));}}
                                    color="blue"
                                />
                                 <Text style={[styles.textFont]}>Blue</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.radioOptions}>
                                <RadioButton
                                    value="red"
                                    status={ themeColor === 'red' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked' }
                                    onPress={() => {saveTheme('red'); setArrowVideoPath(require('../assets/videos/red_arrows.mp4'));}}
                                    color="#DE382A"
                                />
                                <Text style={[styles.textFont]}>Red</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>

              <View style={styles.rowArrow}>
                    <Video
                        ref={videoArrows}
                        style={{width: '100%'}}
                        source={getArrowVideoPath}
                        useNativeControls={false}
                        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
                        onError={(error) => console.error("Video playback error:", error)}
                        isLooping={true}
                        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => {
                            if (!status.isPlaying) {
                                // Handle playback stopped or ended
                                //console.log("status: ", status);
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
```